# How to convert every letter of a string to another letter? in C

Tags: c, string, function, arguments, character

This is my first post, tell me if the format is not approppiate. Thanks.
I'm currently trying to design an algorithm that doing such thing:

It asks for different letters to make a string of n digits, then it asks for a key letter 'cypher key', and then it converts every letter of the string adding the key letter, for example:

```
How many characters? 3  
Next character (1/3)? h  
Next character (2/3)? a  
Next character (3/3)? l  
-> [ h a l ]  
Caesar cypher key? b  
Encrypting...  
-> [ i b m ]
```

Here I leave another example of what the code should do:

```
How many characters? 3  
Next character (1/3)? z  
Next character (2/3)? h  
Next character (3/3)? h  
-> [ z h h ]  
Caesar cypher key? a  
Encrypting...  
-> [ z h h ]
```

In this example, as a=0, the letters will be the same ones

> As you can se it asks for an amount of characters, that will be the size of the string, then you can input the numbers, then it prints the numbers, then it asks for the key letter, it "encrypts" the string, and then it shows the same string but with the value of the key letter added to each one of the letters of the string.

> > Obviously to make that possible ASCII table has to be used.

I'm not very good at using strings and functions, so I may have caused some errors.

> > Here I leave the code with comments (//...) I made for you to see:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20

//argument with no return value function to change the value of str1 with the 'cypher key'.
void moveLetters (char str1[], char cypher_key) {

    int i;  
    int len;
    
    len = strlen(str1);
    
    //loop to convert every character of the string with the cypher key value
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        
        str1[i] = (str1[i] + cypher_key - 97 * 2) % 26 + 97;
    }
}



int main () {
    
    int n_characters;
    char str1[SIZE];
    char cypher_key;
    int i;
    int t = 0;
    
    //asks for the amount of values of the string which can't be less than 0.
    do {
    
        printf ("How many characters? ");
        scanf ("%d", &n_characters);
        
    } while (n_characters <= 0);
    
    //asks for every character depending on the amount.
    for (i = n_characters; i > 0; i--) {
        
        printf ("Next character (%d/%d)? ", t + 1, n_characters);   
        scanf ("%s", &str1[t]);
        
        t++;
                
    }
    
    printf ("-> [%s]\n", str1);
        
    printf ("Caesar cypher key? ");
    scanf ("%s", &cypher_key);
    
    //here I have my doubts because i don't really know if this is a correct way to send a value to a 
    //function and return it to the main
    moveLetters (str1, cypher_key);
    
    printf ("Encrypting...\n");
    
    printf ("-> [%s]", str1);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

> > What happens is that for some reason it prints nothing in the last printf, so i don't understand what happens in the void function or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The last printf works. There is no problem at all.Put a new line so you can see it better.

```
printf ("-> [%s]\n", str1);
```

[image: no problem]

Comment: Hey Yoan, thanks for your comment. Could you send me your code to see exactly where i made the mistake, because it prints nothing anyway in the last printf. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Sergi212 my code is the same as yours. Maybe the problem is in your machine. How do you compile and run your code?